# No https in url when writing links like: <a href="//

Tags: urls, links, https

please help someone , hope you will understand me .

Problems is with <a href="// no https in link
when i try to edit on my web panel , i have correct link with https and when i see my page's code there is not correct link. that's why i have many errors link via one exchanges-link site.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JggB.png]

Comment: What is the PHP code that generates this link?

Comment: sorry , I don't know how to get answer for that

Comment: Please explain a bit more about your solution. Such as: Which theme are you using? Is it on all pages or only on certain ones? And please elaborate a bit on 'I have many errors link via one exchanges-link sites'. Perhaps rephrase it. I don't understand what you mean. :-) ... The two slashes mean: 'Use whatever protocol is being used right now'. So if you're on a page, that has been displayed using HTTP, then the link will be HTTP as well. It was quite popular, when the transition from mostly HTTP to HTTPS was taking place. Nowadays I'd say you're better off just making the link HTTPS.